# Android can't access value in parent Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application i have a next structure of Activities :

```
C ---> B ---> A
```

In Activity A I holds a value, **for example** it's a global `HashMap` of values.

From Activity `C` i start a new activity `D` which extended `B`, so the structure was transform to :

```
   А
   |
   B
  / \
 C   D
```

When i do that - activity `A` was recreated and i loss all data that i stored where(or created new object of activity?)

I play with [launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of `A` but i have no result.

How i can launch new activity and getting access to object in parent Activity?

Comment: Use Application class to hold the global values...

Comment: @Chandrakanth yes, i know about that but I want to get away from the  frequent casts.

Comment: What is the wrong with casting?

Comment: @Chandrakanth i didn't say that something wrong. I just not love that ;)

Comment: you can get the data passed from parent to new child activities sequentially

Comment: @Sudhasri yes. you are right. But passed objects will be need primitive,String or `<T implemets Parcelable>`

Answer (score -1):

#### Working solution. Access to parent object from children activities.

When you start a new activity, application create new instance(new object) of launched Activity and new Activities instances in her hierarchy.

```
   А
   |
   B
  / \
 C   D
```

> I want to read object of A from C and D. 
> **A,B,C,D - Activities.**

Try to launch activity D.

> startActivity(this, D.class)

```
onCreate D
onCreate B
onCreate A
```

So, i found a solution that makes easier developer life (i think).

### What i'm do?

Look at the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class description :

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.

OK, that's exactly what i need. But i didn't want to avoid casting ;( everywhere to application and getting values.

Read more... and see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) callback.

```
abstract void   onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
abstract void   onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
...
```

And i've got an idea.

### In your Application class :

```
private HashMap<Department,ArrayList<Person>> departments;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    // initialize your global object
    departments = new HashMap<Department,ArrayList<Person>>();

    // fill map
    departments.put(...);
    ...
    departments.put(...); 

    // register callbacks
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}
```

### Create annotation

```
/**
 * Created by Sergey Shustikov (pandarium.shustikov@gmail.com)
 */
@Target(value= ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value= RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InjectObject {

}
```

### Mark value in your activity

```
public class A extends Activity {

    @InjectObject
    public HashMap<Department,ArrayList<Person>> departments;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

public class C extends B {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivity(this, D.class);
    }
}

public class D extends B {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person("John Smith"));
        departments.put(new Department("Google"), persons);
    }
}
```

### And the last (magic here :)) :

In Application class :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Field[] fields = activity.getClass().getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(InjectObject.class)) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                if (field.get(activity) == null) {
                    // Inject object
                    field.set(activity, departments);
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to access field %s.", field.getName()), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> After that you can extends any Activity from `A` and getting shareable HashMap.

#### What this happens?

When you start a new activity Application class catch this.  And here we use reflection to inject object. That's all.

Comment: i will explain more wided when i have a free time.